# Is it possible to do concurrent plotting in R of different plots?

Tags: r, matplotlib, plot, concurrency, cairo

I need to draw several thousand plots for my data. With my current code and Cairo png device, it takes 2-3 hours for single dataset, and I have tens of them. I need to know if I can benefit from simultaneous plotting on my multicore CPU, and if not, what is the recommended tool (such as plplot, gnuplot, veusz, matplotlib, matlab, etc.) to do this.
I think, what if I simultaneously launch, say 9, R instances running the plotting code (with multiple `START R.exe CMD BATCH myplot.R` directives from .bat file)?

Comment: I have used matplotlib with multiprocessing in python. It worked well for me.

Comment: Can you give a more clear example of what code you run right now in order to do this plotting? (what does myplot.R look like?)

Comment: I don't know without experimenting, but I would guess that plotting to multiple Cairo devices simultaneously should work fine, either via multiple R instances or by one of the many choices for parallelization within R (`parallel` package, `foreach`, `batchtools` ...)

Comment: @BrianLang it is a rather long function utilising mfrow(1,3) and several subroutines with conditional branching; it takes so long because the timeline of a dataset needs to be split in short chunks and plotted separately into many files, then played back as a video with seeking in both direction still possible and a certain framerate; every plotted frame is independent of each other